# PrintToPrinter in web based application

Tags: crystal-reports

If I call the PrintToPrinter method from a web-based application, will the printing be done on the server's printer or the client's printer?

Answer (score 1):

it would print to server printer

you can't print directly to client printer in web application... you need to call some javascript function `window.print()` in your web page then the browser shows the printer dialog to the user...

Comment: I'm fairly certain you are mistaken and that it will print to the client side printer.

Comment: you can be right IF we are talking about a client-side control executing this code... to me it is not really clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

It will print to client side printer. PrintToPrinter is being called by the CrystalReportViewer control which is rendered in the client's web browser.

Comment: nice.  i rewrote his question to match the sense that you managed to decode from it